# Cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.serializer.Serializer

Tags: java, serialization, apache-spark

I am trying to solve a Spark serialization issue with HashMaps using Java.
I am referring to the link [Save Spark Dataframe into Elasticsearch - Can’t handle type exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667068/save-spark-dataframe-into-elasticsearch-can-t-handle-type-exception/33042316#33042316) .

Now I am hitting the following issue:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.spark.util.umf.MyKryoRegistrator cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.serializer.Serializer
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:259)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
    at com.spark.util.umf.MyMain.main(MyMain.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:480)
15/10/16 01:47:22 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status:
FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception:
com.spark.util.umf.MyKryoRegistrator cannot be cast to
org.apache.spark.serializer.Serializer)
```

I create my `Kryo` registrator as followed :

```java
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoRegistrator;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;

public class MyKryoRegistrator implements KryoRegistrator, Serializable {
    @Override
    public void registerClasses(Kryo kryo) {
        // Product POJO associated to a product Row from the DataFrame            
        kryo.register(MyRecord.class); 
    }
}
```

Main method :

```or-tag-here
public static void main(String args[]){

    SparkConf sConf= new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkTestJob");
    sConf.set( "spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
    //Kryo kryo = new Kryo();;
    //kryo.setDefaultSerializer(MyRecord.class);
    //my.registerClasses(kryo);
    sConf.set("spark.serializer","com.spark.util.umf.MyKryoRegistrator");

    [...]
}
```

Comment: Where is `main` defined?  Please post full code, as it looks like `MyKryoRegistrator` is an inner class, if so try `public static class MyKryoRegistrator` ...

Comment: Ok . It was my mistake . 
I used like "sConf.set("spark.serializer","com.spark.util.umf.MyKryoRegistrator");"

It should be like
sConf.set("spark.kryo.registrator","com.spark.util.umf.MyKryoRegistrator");

Comment: you can put the comment as an answer to your own question  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based of the answer I provided in the link that you have mentioned in your question, you can see that you I have defined both parameters :

`spark.serializer` and `spark.kryo.registrator`

So you have to set both parameters.

If you set the registrator without setting the serializer, the kryo serializer won't be set.