# Why kryo register not work in SparkSession?

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, serialization, kryo

Here's my code:

```
public static SparkSession getTestSparkSession(String name) {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
            .set("spark.master", "local")
            .set("spark.ui.port", "8040")
            .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
            .set("spark.kryo.registrator", "com.test.MyKryoRegistrator");
    return SparkSession.builder()
            .appName(name)
            .config(conf)
            .getOrCreate();
}
```

But it seems that the register does not work:

- Classes which I've registered in registrator still not serializable.
- There're no warning/error logs even I set a wrong registrator class.
- I set the log level to DEBUG, and found there's only one line log about kryo: `DEBUG SparkEnv:58 Using serializer: class org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer`.

Questions:

- How can I check if the registrator works?
- I'm running the spark session by `mvn test`. Does a submit operation is needed?

Comment: You can just ask spark to get you the conf for the registrator.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me more?

Comment: I've checked. The configure set operation succeeds, and I can verify by `getConf` or UI page.  But, it seems that spark did not apply the configure. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to verify that Spark has taken into account your configuration, You can just ask Spark to get you the conf for the registrator.

You just need to get the underlying `SparkContext` from the `SparkSession` and call the getConf function as followed :

```
sparkContext.getConf.get("spark.kryo.registrator") // (this is in scala)
```

Otherwise, you can always check the **Spark UI**.

Now if you wish to force registration, you'll need to set `spark.kryo.registrationRequired` to `true`. (But then you'll need to deal with registering lots of stuff manually)

The default case of that parameter is set to false, so `Kryo` will write unregistered class names along with each object. Writing class names can cause significant performance overhead, so enabling this option can enforce strictly that a user has not omitted classes from registration.

On the other hand, if it is set to 'true', `Kryo` will throw an exception if an unregistered class is serialized.

I advise you to read my other answers about the topic :

- [Save Spark Dataframe into Elasticsearch - Can’t handle type exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667068/save-spark-dataframe-into-elasticsearch-can-t-handle-type-exception/33042316#33042316)
- [Cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.serializer.Serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161377/cannot-be-cast-to-org-apache-spark-serializer-serializer/33164155#33164155)

I hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the Kryo register works. The reason for classes registered still not serializable is that some components cannot be serialized by Kryo. What may be misleading is that the log does not show the reason.

The reason for

> There're no warning/error logs even I set a wrong registrator class.

is the test code has a constructor which calls the class that cannot be serialized by Kryo.