# Spark Kryo: Register a custom serializer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kryo

I have a class that implements a custom Kryo serializer by implementing the `read()` and `write()` methods from `com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Serializer` (see example below). **How can I register this custom serializer with Spark?**

Here is a pseudo-code example of what I have:

```
class A() 

CustomASerializer extends com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Serializer[A]{
    override def write(kryo: Kryo, output: Output, a: A): Unit = ???
    override def read(kryo: Kryo, input: Input, t: Class[A]): A = ???
}

val kryo: Kryo = ... 
kryo.register(classOf[A], new CustomASerializer()); // I can register my serializer
```

Now in Spark:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
sparkConf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[A]))
```

Unfortunately, Spark doesn't give me the option to register my custom serializer. Any idea if there is a way to do this?

Comment: Look at spark.kryo.classesToRegister

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667068/save-spark-dataframe-into-elasticsearch-can-t-handle-type-exception) is not a direct answer to your question but the explanation provided will give you more details about custom serializer registration in spark.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Create your own **`KryoRegistrator`** with this custom serializer registered:

```
package com.acme

class MyRegistrator extends KryoRegistrator {
  override def registerClasses(kryo: Kryo) {
    kryo.register(classOf[A], new CustomASerializer())
  } 
}
```

Then, set `spark.kryo.registrator` to your registrator's fully-qualified name, e.g. `com.acme.MyRegistrator`:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.kryo.registrator", "com.acme.KryoRegistrator")
```

Comment: This isn't very clear in the spark documentation, but this absolutely works. If you run into issues with Kryo not being able to serialize a class with a no-arg constructor in Spark (for me it was org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.LazilyGeneratedOrdering), then this can solve the issue by using kryo.register(LazilyGeneratedOrdering.class, new JavaSerializer()); Thank you!